# Paypal IPN: issue with `chargeback_settlement` orders (emails do not match)

Tags: paypal, ipn

IPN is actually failing for all the order in status `PayPal Canceled Reversal` these orders produce the following errors:

*Requested  and configured mymail@mail.com merchant emails do not match. in .../Model/Paypal/Ipn.php:257* ( `Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn::_verifyOrder()`)

Looking a the request I can see the correct email is present but it is stored into `payer_email` while the `_verifyOrder()` is checking for values stored in `business` or `receiver_email`

I'm quite sure this is a bug in Magento IPN.

Can somebody confirm if experience the same issue ?

Comment: What version of Magento are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure because we updated the store ...

Comment: I'm currently having the same thing but with Payment process, although all payments are going through without a problem. Can you post your entire Magento stack trace error? I know what the issue is and it's not fatal if your transactions are going through.

Comment: answer is here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/203672/44358

Answer (score 1):

We are currently experiencing the same issue. Strangely enough it seemed to start only after the update to 1.9.3.4. But I guess that was just coincidence.

I would modify the _verifyOrder method to use `payer_email` if `reason_code` is `chargeback_settlement`. But I wasn't able to test that yet.