# requested email doesnt match with merchant emails do not match

Tags: magento-2.1, email, paypal

I checked the debug file and found that  `exception` => The requested `xoxoxo@gmail.com` and configured `xoxoxo@mydomain.com` merchant emails do not match.

I have a Paypal account with few different email address and G-mail account has been set as a primary account in google.

Is it Ok?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**Email Associated with PayPal Merchant Account `(Optional)`** field is optional as you can see in screenshot or insert *Paypal **Primary** email address* `xoxoxo@gmail.com` in that field then you will never receive this message in log file.